# Efficient way to store a Map of Maps in Hazelcast?

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am currently using Hazelcast to distribute my data across a network. The implementation uses an IMap of objects that I want to store. However, each of these objects is essentially just a HashMap, so I have been wondering if there is a more efficient way to distribute a "map of maps" using Hazelcast.

I have read up on [this long-forgotten issue](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/147) on their bug tracker, but no progress has been made on implementing the functionality.

In the absence of this as a core Hazelcast feature, is there any more efficient way of managing this kind of data structure other than my current "`IMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>`" approach?

Comment: Why don't you create a container class that will replace the `HashMap<String, String>`? You can have the get, add, and other Map methods implemented there.

Comment: I do - `HashMap<String, String>` was just an example. If I had to guess at the inefficiency in the current implementation, it's that Hazelcast doesn't look deeper into the inner map. So when I need to update an object in the inner map, I have to get the object out, change values as required, then replace the whole object within the Hazelcast IMap. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way, where Hazelcast could understand more about what it's handling.

Comment: If the object is mutable, then you should not have any problem directly `get()`-ting the object and working over it (opposed to having to do as you mentioned)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the case with Hazelcast - the object is mutable, but changes made directly to it seem to be ignored by Hazelcast and are not propagated over the network. Am I missing something in my Hazelcast config?

Comment: (See the item titled "How do I reflect value modifications" in the [Hazelcast FAQ](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.2/manual/html/faq.html).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hazelcast doesn't support a map of map of key, values. But one possible solution would be to make use of a composite key:

```
String employeeId = "1234"
String attribute = "name"
map.put(employeeId+"#"+attribute, "peter")
```

However, be warned. If you need to access many values since for every access you need a round trip. Another disadvantage is that is is difficult to get all key2/values for a key1 (e.g. find all attributes for employee 1234).

Another approach, which prevents doing unwanted serialization/deserialization is combining a map as value with all access through an EntryProcessor. This way you have very fine control on the data being send/returned + with the EntryProcessor you don't need to be worried about data-races since that is provided by the EntryProcessor out of the box. The API might not be that pretty, but it would probably do the trick in a very efficient manner. In this case I would suggest using the OBJECT in memory format. Another advantage of this approach is that it is easy to get all values, since they are grouped in the hashmap-value. However, if you have an 'infinite' number of columns, this could lead to problems since the hashmap value isn't distributed. This is not an issue with the composite key approach.

So it depends a bit on your usecase what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have implemented the EntityProcessor suggestion and it has significantly reduced the memory usage of my application! Since I regularly need to access all the values in the "inner" maps I'm not sure the composite key solution will be efficient, but I will give it a try.

Comment: The composite key probably won't be the best solution if you need to access many/all. Since for every key you need to do a potential remote call. With the map as value in combination with entry processors, you can prevent this.

Comment: Hazelcast provide MultiMap as well where you can store multiple object against single key if it suites your use case. Please check below link for details [Hazelcast MultiMap Doc](https://hazelcast.org/mastering-hazelcast/#multimap)

Answer (score 2):

> The implementation uses an IMap of objects that I want to store. However, each of these objects is essentially just a HashMap

Instead of using IMap to store HashMap you could probably just store in the main IMap just identifier for the HashMap corresponding to certain key and store all the child maps in Hazelcast as well.

Instead of `IMap<String, HashMap>`
use `IMap<String, SomeStringId>` and get corresponding `HashMap` with `HazlecastInstance.getMap(SomeStringId)` - that way you'll still need to put values back into Hazelcast after mutating, but you'll put just one value - not the whole map.

```
IMap main = hazelcastInstance.getMap("Main"); 
String childMapName = main.get(key);
IMap childMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap(childMapName); 
Object value = childMap.get(childKey);
value.changeSmth();
childMap.put(chlidKey,value);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this might be too late to answer your problem, but I bumped into the same problem when I tried to create my own implementation of distributed user session for my chat service.

So what I did was serializing my **Map** to **byte[]** then persisting it to hazelcast's **IMap**.
 Check below code:

```
IMap<String, byte[]> distributedMap = hazelcast.getMap(MAP_NAME);

Map<String, Serializable> myMap = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(myMap);

distributedMap.put(sessionId, baos.toByteArray());
```

And when I try to retrieve the persisted user session, what I do is like below code.

```
IMap<String, byte[]> distributedMap = hazelcast.getMap(MAP_NAME);

byte[] raw = distributedMap.get(sessionId);
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
Map<String, Serializable> myMap = (Map<String, Serializable>) ois.readObject();
```

Then after I get my **Map** back, I can do anything with that. I hope this will help anybody who required to do the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Since Hazelcast Map does not watch the state of the object as given value, using IMap with Hashmap objects(value) meaningless if you add or remove values inner HashMap which change  will not shared in cluster.

Hazelcast only shares reference changes in its containers. So you you should have a single IMap with single joined key as **key1 + "WhatEverString"+ key2**.

If you are giving reference of inner HashMap to IMap every time when you change the state of inner HashMap, Hazelcast will reserialize whole inner map and it will have less performance.